# How to use strchr() multiple times to find the nth occurrence

Tags: c, string

I am trying to figure out a way to make this work:

```
//Returns a pointer to the nth char in a string
const char *nth_strchr(const char *s, int c, int n) {
    int c_count = 0;
    char *nth_ptr;

    while (c_count++ != n) {
        nth_ptr = strchr(s, c);
        //need a line here to skip past the previous found occurrence.
    }
    return nth_ptr;
}
```

I am not too sure how I can make it so each iteration of the `while` loop can acknowledge the occurrence/position of the char found in the previous loop. Since I have the pointer to that first occurrence... I was thinking of using the memory address to increment the next loop so that I could give the next `strchr()` call the string starting at the `c + 1` position? 
Is that possible at all?

Comment: `if (nth_ptr==NULL) break; else nth_ptr++;`

Comment: What does [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) return? A pointer to the character it found in the string (or `NULL` if not found). Now think a little how you could use that to get to the next character in the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char* nth_strchr(const char* s, int c, int n)
{
    int c_count;
    char* nth_ptr;

    for (c_count=1,nth_ptr=strchr(s,c); 
         nth_ptr != NULL && c_count < n && c!=0; 
         c_count++) 
    {
         nth_ptr = strchr(nth_ptr+1, c);
    }

    return nth_ptr;
}
```

This code has been tested.

Comment: Although this code is neat, it reduces readability. Using fancy functions of a programming language to reduce lines of code is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset I have seen such code style in the sources of Linux and MS Visual Studio. As for me this code style is ok. if I will edit project with another code style, I will use another code style (style accepted by the project). but here is a just extension of common library function, so imho here such style is acceptable.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I disagree. In this context the reader is probably someone new to C that wants to learn, and the code you present is not necessarily the best at teaching. Sure it is correct but it is unnecessarily complex imho.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious (?) way is of course to use the return value of `strchr()` as the new string, after adding 1 to step past the occurrence known to be there, yes.

Something like:

```
const char * nth_strchr(const char *s, int c, int n)
{
  for (;;)
  {
    if (n <= 0)
      return NULL;
    const char *h = strchr(s, c);
    if(h == NULL)
      return NULL;
    if (--n == 0)
      return h;
    s = h + 1;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are after the `n`th occurrence of `c` in the string `s`, and not the `n`th char as your comment says, then this line

```
s = nth_ptr + 1;
```

at the end of your loop will advance your `s` pointer to the char after the `c_count`th occurence of `c` in `s`.

Remember to also check the return value from `strchr` as mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code could be as simple as this, using a counted (`for`) loop with an early escape if there aren't `n` occurrences of the character `c` in the string `s`:

```
const char *nth_strchr(const char *s, int c, int n) 
{
    const char *nth = s;
    assert(c != '\0');

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((nth = strchr(nth, c)) == 0)
            break;
        nth++;
    }

    return nth;
}
```

The `break;` could be replaced by `return 0;` or `return NULL;`.  The condition could be `== NULL` instead of `== 0`.  I've assumed at least C99; if you don't have that available, then you need to define `i` outside the loop.

The assertion is the utmost pedantry.  You can't go incrementing the pointer beyond the first null without detailed knowledge of how the code will be used, and without a context that makes it a sane option.

Other answers have a similar net effect, but IMO the code isn't as clearly written (which is why I've added an answer this much later).  Spreading the controls of a loop over three lines and using multiple assignments in the setup makes it harder to read than it need be.  Using an infinite loop when a counted loop is called for seems like obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you keep locating the first occurrence of `c`, you should add `s = nth_ptr + 1;` if `nth_ptr` is not `NULL`, but you should make special cases for `n == 0` and/or `c == '\0'`.

Here is a simpler version:

```
const char *nth_strchr(const char *s, int c, int n) {
    if (c == '\0' && n > 1)  /* special case the null terminator */
        return NULL;
    if (n > 0) {
        while ((s = strchr(s, c)) != NULL && --n > 0) {
            s++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: you forgot closing braces.

Answer (score -1):

//Try This program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char *q,arr[]="This is strchr i program";
int i=0;
while((q=strchr(arr+i,'i'))!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n",q);
    i=(char *)q-(char *)arr;
    i=i+1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps add an explanation as to what you improved?